# Large gap between foundation wall and patio

Tags: concrete

What is the best way to full this gap which is between the foundation wall and front patio?[image]

Comment: Why not jack it back up by wedging new base-stone under the descending edge(e) of the patio?

Answer (score 1):

Use wood to cover the end of the gap, mix cement and pour it in.